# Python relative imports limits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Is there a limit to the number of `.` that are allowed in python relative imports? I have a project in which all the imports are relative and it behaves well, except for a module where there is the command

```
from ....Infrastructure.Enums import FieldRolls
```

I got the following error:

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

when I changed the command to import with 3 dots it worked.

I also checked the `__name__` and `__package__` variables and they looks OK.

Comment: There are probably only 3 levels to top level package and you try to climb one step too high...

Comment: This is not true. If I try to move over the to level it gives an error 'attempt to move over the top level' or something like this. Anyway I got the error in another location (with 2 dots) so the problem is another problem

Comment: Wrong guess then :-( . Honestly I could only imagine that problem, hence my previous comment. Maybe you should try to control the hierarchy of `__init__.py` files and their content.